# Logic Architectural Model: references for further understanding?

Tags: java, service, architecture

I am having trouble understanding the `Logical Architectural Model` and how it relates to `Service Orientated Architecture`.    e.g:

[image: Model Diagram]

I do not get the general principle behind it and how each of the `services` connect (i.e. talk to one another). Does anyone have any links/resources to help with understanding this?

The only link I have found so far is from the [IBM Website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0710_tost/0710_tost.html) which has not been much help.

I am also confused about the `Physical Architecture Model` of SOA works? And what its main components are?

Comment: First of all, where's the source of the image? It seems to be from an Oracle training

Comment: It is from the IBM website, from the hyperlink provided

Answer (score 2):

The best place to find what you're looking for is reading the [IBM SOA Foundation: An Architectural Introduction](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-soa-whitepaper.pdf) whitepaper by IBM. Another excellent resource to understand this is the [Patterns: SOA Foundation Service Creation Scenario](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247240.pdf).

I will try to explain most of the boxes, maybe in an over-simplified way:

- **Interaction Services** are about presentation logic and allowing the user to access your solution. A typical component in this layer would be a Portal Application, that in IBM World it means an IBM WebSphere Portal solution.
- **Process Services** are services in charge of composing logic, and the IBM-way to do that is through Business Process Flows deployed on IBM WebSphere Process Server.
- **Business Application Services** are were your business logic is: these are the components composed by the flows in the Process Service Layer. In a typical solution components here are Web Services deployed in IBM WebSphere Application Server.
- **Information Services** are -according to the book- where the "data logic" resides, including Business Intelligence components. I believe IBM DB2 Database has several functionality to handle this.
- **Access Services** are generally wrappers to expose legacy applications through Web Services.
- **Partner Services** gives your solution the capabilities to interact with external partners/suppliers. To give a simple example, here to can have Services that allow you the consumption of Services that are exposed by an external supplier, which will become in this case the Partner Service Provider.

The remaining boxes are supporting elements of your architecture, and are not related to Business Design, although they're important for the IBM SOA Foundation.

In relation to the Physical Architecture Model, the [IBM SOA Foundation: An Architectural Introduction](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-soa-whitepaper.pdf) describes it very clearly and has a nice diagram of it:

[image]

As with the Logical Architecture Model, I'll describe some of the boxes:

- Every service request traverse the **ESB Server**.
- Using a **Gateway**, you can select which Services are visible to the Internet.
- The **Firewall Server**  limits protocols and ports visible from outside your intranet, allowing the creation of a De-militarized zone (DMZ)
- The **Proxy Server** has several responsibilities. We can mention page caching and workload distribution among others.
- The **Portal Server** hosts the Interaction Services .
- The **Process Server** hosts the Process Services.
- The **Application Server** hosts the Business Application Services.
- The **Security Server** manages identity and authorization management.
- The **Management Server** monitors the entire Service Environment.

Comment: Thank you, do u have any references/resources for learning about the physical model, i.e. servers etc

Comment: I edited the answer to include a brief description of it

Comment: Thank you. What I really need to know is how the services talk to one another/interact within the Logical architecture Model? Can you help me with that, thanks!